# Decrasing Non uniform distribution of a gene

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I currently have a gene that can take an integer value in [1, 1500].

I don't like the 1500 upper bound that is acting like a magic number. Each integer can be selected uniformely, however when exploring I feel that a change from 1 to 2 is not the same as a change from 1001 to 1002 (but both have the same probability).

Is there a common/known way to :

1. select a value non uniformely, with a decreasing probability : say a 'small' value ('5' for instance) as a higher probability to be selected than a medium value ('200' for instance), and a 'medium' value has a higher probability to be selected than a high value ('1000' for instance), 'higher' needing to be defined somehow...
2. explore the full integers range without bounding but avoid to have crazy high value from the start (maybe something like a bounded evolutive range)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this not a programming question. This is a conceptual question, which you should probably ask on https://ai.stackexchange.com/ or another website where genetic algorithms are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about a random distributions, for example a normal distribution?

With a normal distribution you specify the *center* of your random values as well as the the *width* of the standard deviation. The random numbers generated by such a normal distribution have a much higher likelihood to be near the specified center rather than in value areas that are 1, 2 or 3 standard deviations away. The distribution of values from a normal distribution looks like this:

[image: normal distribution plot]
Source: [3]

You can read more on normal distributions or standard deviations on Wikipedia [2] [3]

If you don't like this particular probability distribution because you think it is too flat or too step then there are plenty of other distributions to choose from.

---

In code this could be implemented like this with Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
gene_value = int(np.abs(rng.normal(loc=0, scale=500)))
```

This makes use of the Numpy random normal generator [4]. The center is set to 0 and the standard deviation to 500, making values closer to 0 significantly more likely and values close to 1500 or even higher very unlikely.

---

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

[4] https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.normal.html